# Индекс за пределами диапазона. Индекс должен быть положительным числом, а его размер не должен превышать размер коллекции

Tags: c#, словари, datagridview

Есть словарь, в котором ключ - номер чека, значение - список из покупок.
При попытке добавить значение словаря в DataGridView возникает исключение "Индекс за пределами диапазона. Индекс должен быть положительным числом, а его размер не должен превышать размер коллекции".
В чем может быть проблема? В обычный Label все выводится без проблем.

```
 label3.Text = null;
            foreach(KeyValuePair<int, List<string>> KeyValue in tidDB.tidDict)
            {
                label3.Text += KeyValue.Key.ToString();
                foreach(string str in KeyValue.Value)
                {
                    label3.Text += str + ",";
                }
                label3.Text += Environment.NewLine;
            }
            dataGridView3.DataSource = null;
            dataGridView3.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
            dataGridView3.ColumnCount = 2;
            dataGridView3.Columns[0].Name = "Номер чека";
            dataGridView3.Columns[1].Name = "Список покупок";
            //dataGridView3.DataSource = tidDB.tidDict.ToArray();
            int i = 0;
            foreach(KeyValuePair<int, List<string>> KeyValue in tidDB.tidDict)
            {

                    dataGridView3.Rows[i].Cells["Номер чека"].Value = KeyValue.Key;
                    foreach(string str in KeyValue.Value)
                    {
                        dataGridView3.Rows[i].Cells["Список покупок"].Value = KeyValue.Value.ToString() + ",";
                    }
                i++;


                //dataGridView3.Rows.Add(KeyValue.Key);
                //dataGridView3.Rows.Add(KeyValue.Value);
            }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У вас изначально `Rows` например нет, а вы пытаетесь по индексу их взять. Может не `.Rows[i]...`, а `.Rows.Add(...)`? Также и с колонками смотрите что они имеют в себе, предположу, что там тоже пустая коллекция из которой вы хотите получить мистический элемент.

Answer (score 1):

Решила проблему, добавив строку, которая добавляет пустую строку, чтобы к существующей строке можно было обращаться по индексу. Не знаю, конечно, насколько правильно это решение, но, по крайней мере, заработало.

```
                int i = 0;
            foreach(KeyValuePair<int, List<string>> KeyValue in tidDB.tidDict)
            {
                dataGridView3.Rows.Add(); // добавить строку, чтобы можно было обращаться к уже существующей строке по индексу
                dataGridView3.Rows[i].Cells["Номер чека"].Value = KeyValue.Key;
                    foreach(string str in KeyValue.Value)
                    {
                        dataGridView3.Rows[i].Cells["Список покупок"].Value += str + " ";
                    }
                i++;
            }
```